# How can we append or concat multiple files with mostly similar schemas but not all

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to combine a bunch of text files, all tab delimited, into one file, and save it as in  CSV format.  Some of the schemas are the same, but fields in newer files don't always exist in older files.  Also, I want to add the file name in the last column in each row.

Field names could be like this in all files:

```
RIAD4097    RIAD4235    RIAD4239
```

Newer files could have this (these are missing in the older files):

```
RIADJA28    RIADKW02
```

Here is the code that I am testing, but I'm getting an error.

```
import os, glob
import pandas as pd

path = "C:\\Users\\ryans\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\schemas\\"

all_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(path, "*.txt"))

all_df = []
for f in all_files:
    df = pd.read_csv(f, delimiter='\t')
    f['file'] = f.split('/')[-1]
    all_df.append(df,f)
    
merged_df = pd.concat(all_df, ignore_index=True, sort=True)
df_merged.to_csv("C:\\Users\\ryans\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\merged.csv")
```

This line throws an error.

```
f['file'] = f.split('/')[-1]
```

Error is:

> TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment

I am trying to get the file name listed in the very last column, in every row.

Based on my research, I think the append method should work, and I think the concat method would work, as an alternative.  Is there a preferred way to do this kind of thing?  Thanks!!

Comment: Is there any error or undesired results with attempted code? `pd.concat` does not require same columns.

Comment: I just updated my original post.  So, if the field names are the same, it appends new records under prior records?  If a new names that don't match are simply added and the matching data is appended underneath?

Comment: All rows are appended with `concat`. If column names do not match, `NaN` is filled for those rows. Are you trying to vertically stack (i.e., *append*) or horizontally join (i.e., *merge*)? `concat` can do both.

Comment: Sorry for not being more clear here.  Let's say file1 has columns named A, B, C, and D. Also, file2 has columns named A, B, C, D, and E. I want the A, B, C, and D from file2 appended under file1, and column E, from file2, added as a new column, and all the rows from file1 will have NANs in column E, but the data from file2 will be filled in for column E. I want to capture all the data from files that are similar, create a single data frame, and push that to a SQL Server table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `os.path.basename(f)` to extract file name. And to save a new column assign with `[]` not with `list.append`.

```py
import os
...

all_df = [] 

for f in all_files: 
   df = pd.read_csv(f, delimiter='\t') 
   df['file'] = os.path.basename(f)     # NEW COLUMN
   all_df.append(df) 

df_append = pd.concat(all_df, ignore_index=True, sort=True)
df_append.to_csv("C:\\Users\\ryans\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\merged.csv")
```

Even better use list comprehension with `assign` to add new column:

```py
all_df = [(pd.read_csv(f, delimiter='\t')
             .assign(file=os.path.basename(f)) for f in all_files]

df_append = pd.concat(all_df, ignore_index=True, sort=True)
df_append.to_csv("C:\\Users\\ryans\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\merged.csv")
```